Elliptic curve and vector bundle extensions

Let $C$ be an elliptic curve. Show that $H^1(C, \mathcal{O}_C) \cong \Bbb C$ and use this to construct a nonsplitting extension $0 \rightarrow \mathcal{O} \rightarrow E \rightarrow \mathcal{O} \rightarrow 0$. Prove that $E$ cannot be written as a direct sum of two
holomorphic line bundles. (There is an algebraic argument using $H^1 (C, \mathcal{O}_C) \cong \text{Ext}^1(\mathcal{O}_C , \mathcal{O}_C)$ , but one might as well try to construct a new $\bar{\partial}$-operator on the trivial bundle of rank two
by means of a representative of a non-trivial class in $H^1 (C, \mathcal{O}_C) = H^{0,1} (C)$.)

If $C$ is an elliptic curve, Serre duality says that $$H^1(C,\mathcal{O}_C)\cong H^0(C,\omega_C\otimes \mathcal{O}^\vee_C)^*$$ and $\mathcal{O}^\vee_C \cong \mathcal{O}_C$ so $H^1(C,\mathcal{O}_C) \cong H^0(C,\omega_C)^*$. Now $dz$ is a non-vanishing $1$-form on $\omega_C$ so it is trivial and hence $H^0(C,\omega_C) \cong \Bbb C$.
I would like to understand the both suggestions given in the problem statement. I'm quite new to this so I have bunch of questions. If I take for granted that $H^1 (C, \mathcal{O}_C) \cong \text{Ext}^1(\mathcal{O}_C , \mathcal{O}_C)$, then as $H^1 (C, \mathcal{O}_C)$ is non-trivial there exists a non-trivial extension $0 \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_C \rightarrow E \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_C \rightarrow 0$.

If $E \cong L_1 \oplus L_2$, how can I argue to get a contradiction here?
How does the non-trivial class of $H^1(C,\mathcal{O}_C)$ give us a new $\bar{\partial}$-operator?


First, a point of terminology: it makes sense to say "$dz$ is a non-vanishing $1$-form on $C$" or "$dz$ is a non-vanishing section of $\omega_C$," but as written that sentence is a bit confusing. Regarding (1), if $E$ is a direct sum then you have projection maps onto the summands (as well as inclusions) that you should be able to play around with to get a splitting of an isomorphic extension or vanishing of the extension class (I'm not 100% sure what you want to prove).

Algebraic argument:
If $ E $ is a direct sum of line bundles $ L_1 $ and $ L_2 $, then $ L_1 \otimes L_2 = \det E = \mathcal{O}_C $. That is, $ E = L \oplus L^{\vee} $ for some line bundle $ L $.
Composing the quotient $ E \to \mathcal{O}_C $ with inclusions $ L \to E $ and $ L^{\vee} \to E $ gives sections of $ L^{\vee} $ and $ L $ respectively. These sections cannot both be non-zero as that would imply $ L $ is trivial, a contradiction as $ E $ is a nontrivial extension. These sections cannot both be zero either, as $ E \to \mathcal{O}_C $ is surjective.
So assume without loss of generality that the section of $ L $ is non-zero and the section of $ L^{\vee} $ is zero. Then $ L \to E $ factors through $ L \to \mathcal{O}_C \to E $ as $ \mathcal{O}_C \to E $ is the kernel of the quotient $ E \to \mathcal{O}_C $. But since $ L $ has a nonzero section, $ L^{\vee} $ has only the zero section. So the inclusion $ L \to E $ is zero, a contradiction.
Constructing $ E $ from a $ \bar{\partial} $-operator directly:
In general, if $ E $ is a holomorphic vector bundle on a complex manifold $ X $, we may deform the holomorphic structure on $ E $ by a class $ \kappa $ in $ H^{0,1}(X, \operatorname{End} E) = H^1(X, \operatorname{End} E) $ in the following way: if $ \xi $ represents the class of $ \kappa $, we may write a new operator $ \bar{\partial}_E + \xi \wedge ( \cdot ) $ on the complex of smooth $ (0,q) $-forms valued in $ E $. It is not difficult to check that this squares to zero, hence defines a holomorphic structure on the underlying complex vector bundle of $ E $.
In this case, take the trivial holomorphic bundle of rank 2 on $ C $ whose underlying complex vector bundle is also trivial. The trivial holomorphic structure is induced by the matrix $$ \begin{pmatrix}
\bar{\partial} & 0 \\
0 & \bar{\partial} 
\end{pmatrix} $$
Let $ \kappa $ be a basis for $ H^1(C, \mathcal{O}_C) $ and $ \xi $ a $ (0,1) $-form representing $ \kappa $. Deform the holomorphic structure on the trivial bundle via the new matrix $$ \begin{pmatrix}
\bar{\partial} & \xi \wedge ( \cdot) \\
0 & \bar{\partial} 
\end{pmatrix} $$
I claim that this structure gives us such an extension $ E $. To see this, note that $ \mathcal{O}_C $ is a subbundle of $ E $ by inclusion $ f \to (f,0) $ and that $ \mathcal{O}_C $ is also a quotient of $ E $ by projection $ (f,g) \to g $. It is also clear that from these maps, we get an exact sequence $ 0 \to \mathcal{O}_C \to E \to \mathcal{O}_C \to 0 $
It remains to show $ E $ is not the trivial extension. If it is, we would have a global section of $ E $ of the form $ (h,1) $. Then $ \bar{\partial}h + \xi = 0 $ gives a contradiction $ \kappa = [\xi] = [\bar{\partial}(-h)] = 0 $.
